# What is an "opposite" to "biological conservation worker"

Tags: expressions, antonyms

The topic of the debate will be: **Maintaining at least proportion of old trees within managed forest stands as roost for animals (not to cut them down).**

I need to **properly express** the names of two groups in a debate.

May it be:
             **(FOR) = Conservationist**
             **(AGAINST)  = (forest) practicioners?**

*P.S. I know that people responsible for forest management may be pro-conservation also, so please do not stone me!*

Comment: This is an inherently "loaded" question. There are many people with many different ideas about how to manage/preserve/exploit natural resources. Labeling one group *conservationists* because they want to retain some old trees for use by animals implicitly classifies all other approaches as "anti-conservation", even though it might be screamingly obvious to professional ecologists that in the specific context it would be a very bad idea to keep those old trees. (I'm not a professional ecologist, so I can't cite specific reasons why that might be so.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that we could come up with a set of terms for the pro/con sides of the argument that wouldn't necessarily cast one or the other in a bad light. Rereading the question, I don't think the OP has determined that he is going to use "conservationist" for one side. I think it was the best word he could think of and is open to other suggestions.

Comment: @ColleenV: Well I can't deny your  Conservationist/Preservationist distinction could be appropriate in some contexts. But assuming there are only two groups of people with differing views in OP's "debate", I think there would almost always be inherent bias in selecting *any* pair of labels for the supporters of each approach. Anyway, on considering the question again myself, I think it's currently Unclear, since we don't actually *know* how each side justifies wishing to retain/cut down the old trees.

Comment: How about " _proponents_ of minimum ratios of older trees VS. _opponents_ of minimum ratios of older trees."  That is, after all, what they are debating.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that your point about the labels biasing the audience would actually make for a great answer suggesting more neutral names like Pro/Con or Red Team/Blue Team. I don't think you have to capture the whole of the debate in the naming of the sides. This isn't tabloid news after all :)

Comment: @ColleenV: I think the general practice in such contexts is to "label" the debate itself with either a straightforward statement or a proposed course of action, after which the two sides (assuming there are meaningfully only two possible positions) can be identified as ***For/Against***. But even that might sometimes be contentious - some of the people thereby labeled ***Against*** might prefer to negate the original statement, so they can be more "positively" labeled ***For***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree it is a hairy problem, but I think it is on-topic here because there are quite a few traps for the non-native speaker even though it might fall into the gray area toward opinion based. How negative is being labelled "Anti" versus "Con"? I think there's a reason why certain groups prefer to label themselves "pro-life" and "pro-choice". I think we could offer some word choices supported by facts and expertise however.

Comment: @ColleenV: Your *pro-life vs pro-choice* pair is telling - nobody wants to be labeled *anti-life* or *anti-choice*. But at least there most of us understand the (moral) issues and conflicts involved. To restate the point in my first comment, most people here won't have the faintest idea why "thoughtful, well-intentioned, well-informed" people might support either side in OP's debate. How to label them is really just a matter of (ignorant) opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think not knowing the exact nature of the arguments being presented makes it easier to choose neutral names that won't bias the audience ahead of time. You don't want them to know ahead of time who they support. The point of debate used to be to help people make up their minds not preach to the converted.

Answer (score 2):

Within the naturalist field there are [Conservationists and Preservationists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preservationist). Keep in mind however, that conservationist when it is used outside of this specific field has a more general meaning of "someone who wants to preserve the environment".

Preservationists believe it is important to leave the wild areas largely untouched, and conservationists believe it is important to actively manage the wild areas for human use/enjoyment. I'm not sure these two groups would be completely opposed on the topic of the debate, but they would definitely have different perspectives on whether the trees should be harvested if they're not healthy or left in place solely for the benefit of the animals.

Comment: @LadislavNado I'm glad it helped! I would suggest however that you wait a little while before accepting any answers. Someone may have a better suggestion than I do. This might help explain: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161

Answer (score 1):

The opposite (or, at least, one possible opposite) of **conservation** is **exploitation**: ["use or utilization, especially for profit"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exploitation).

There are a few problems with this, though. First of all, while 'conservationist' is a fairly well known word, 'exploitationist' isn't one I've seen. 
Second, while it is accurate, 'exploitation' has a negative connotation that your debaters might object to.